# How to use RSpec to set up expectations for top level methods on a Sinatra App?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, sinatra

Spec helper:

```
def app
  Sinatra::Application
end
```

App:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  track_request
  "Welcome"
end

def track_request
  puts self.inspect
  ....
end
```

How to mock `track_request`?

```
allow(app).to receive :track_request
allow_any_instance_of(Sinatra::Application).to receive :track_request
allow(Sinatra::Application).to receive :track_request
```

None of these worked.

`self` is main, so I guess we need to mock a method on main. But didn't find out how to do it.

Comment: There might be a difference in the test environment setup. I was able to mock the method just fine. https://gist.github.com/kgrz/4ea34a6cf79502c3eda678d6760b34b1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not possible? (so far I'm stumped)

After reading this blog post: http://www.philandstuff.com/2012/02/12/surprises-while-testing-sinatra-controllers.html

It looks like Sinatra dups your controller before handling an HTTP request.

*From 'sinatra/base.rb'*

```
# Rack call interface.
def call(env)
   dup.call!(env)
end
```

It seems like this would be a common thing to do when testing a Sinatra app. I'm surprised there isn't a clear solution.

Comment: Anything is possible.